# Milnor's octahedron

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, math-history, tensors

If $V$ is a vector space, then a curvaturelike tensor in $V$ is a quadrilinear map $F:V \times V \times V \times V \to \Bbb R$ satisfying

1) $F(x,y,z,w) = -F(y,x,z,w) = -F(x,y,w,z)$;

2) $F(x,y,z,w) = F(z,w,x,y)$;

3) $F(x,y,z,w) + F(y,z,x,w) + F(z,x,y,w) = 0$,

for all $x,y,z,w \in V$. It turns out that the Bianchi identity (item 3) actually implies item 2, assuming 1. This implication is called "[Milnor's octahedron argument](https://people.math.osu.edu/derdzinski.1/courses/7711/octahedron.pdf)".

I'd like to know where this appeared for the first time. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it's truly the first appearance, but it seems likely the name originates from Milnor's classic 1963 book *Morse Theory*, in which you can find the following illustrated argument: [image: milnor's illustration and argument]

Here (1), (2) and (3) are your 1) and 3), with (4) being your conclusion 2).